# LAMP hosting on AWS Cloud - what PHP code to re-write?

Tags: database-design, amazon-ec2, cloud, scalability, yii

I want to host a PHP application on Cloud to take advantage of on-demand scalability. I am afraid if my application were to get featured on *Digg/Slashdot/popular blogs* (hopefully all of these places) then my site would very likely crash. So, I was looking into A*mazon EC2, RackSpace Cloud Servers etc.* But I am confused by **Cloud Architecture**. Hosting a PHP application on regular cPanel based shared-hosting is very simple. FTP upload your code to public_html directory and you are done.

But with cloud, we'd have multiple servers. My understanding is that in Cloud, you get some VM space behind some load-balancer. When you need more resources, you simply provision another VM. Load balancer sends request to all available resources. 
So, how do you deal with these things:

- **Session management/session continuity**: 
  Now, one of the obvious thing here is that Cloud-Server-1 is not going to be aware of user-session on Cloud-Server-2. So, how is this managed in cloud based hosting? Would I be required to re-write some PHP code that deals with sessions?
  (I am thinking of hosting an e-commerce PHP script done in **Yii** framework)
- Would the PHP code that deals with session need to be re-written or
  is there an abstraction layer that handles it? Basically, do I simply
  FTP upload the application and then some abstraction layer takes care
  of everything or do I have to re-write some code?
- **Database scaling**: When there is heavy load, I think I can configure Amazon EC2 or any cloud-server to automatically provision more servers. And besides, it's probably a good idea to have multiple servers anyway to increase speed and reliability. But I am not sure how that works. I mean, the "data" in the database has to be shared.

So, **how are multiple database-servers maintained?** If each database is a real-time copy of each other. Then how will it reduce load? I mean, if you do a query on DB1, and then in real-time, this query is also done in DB2 (if not, the data in DB2 would not be same as DB1) then both DB will have same load.

Some Cloud Servers I am considering are:

1. Amazon EC2
2. RackSpace Cloud Sites
3. RackSpace Cloud Servers
4. PagodaBox (still in BETA and does not allow crons though): http://www.pagodabox.com/
5. Go Grid scalable website architecture: http://www.gogrid.com/cloud-hosting/cloud-hosting-packages/scalable-website.php (*although this is very very expensive. I was hoping to start with a single server to begin with and then automatically provision extra web-servers and/or extra DB-servers to handle load spikes as needed*)

Any tips would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: First, read [this article](http://teddziuba.com/2008/04/im-going-to-scale-my-foot-up-y.html) by Ted Dziuba on scaling. Then, proceed.

Comment: yeah, let's assume that the site does get featured on Digg etc. and "Scalability" really is my problem. Also, let's say the PHP app is a vendor app. Something like ModernBill, OSCommerce, Magento etc. and the target number of users == 3 million unique users. 25% active per day of the month.

Comment: While this is a good question, it may be a bit to broad for this forum. To address one of your specific questions about sessions, if you are using Yii, you can use a [database as session data storage](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbHttpSession) or other network storage using apps like Redis or similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I talked to tech-support of a hosting company. He didn't seem like a uber-geek but he gave me this advise: create multiple web-servers & multiple DB servers. Here is how:

- **Multiple web servers**: he said you should load image of your
  application on multiple servers. Start-up 1 server initially. If the
  load is high, start-up the other image. Load balancer would
  automatically start sending queries to this new instance of your web
  server.
- **DB Servers**: create multiple DB servers. 1 master and several
  slaves.

He said, you'd need to rewrite some **PHP code** and do the following:

1. **Session handling**: he said modify your PHP code so that sessions are stored in "DB" .
2. **DB related code**:  Remove all "join" operations. I am not sure if this is even possible to remove ALL join operations. *Any tips on how to do this?* Is there no way to "scale" while retaining "**join**" operations?

That's all. Really, is it this it? Or do you think there are other things to take care of as well?

Also, to create multiple DB server instances (master-slave). Write to master only. I would need have at-least two (2) DB servers running at ALL times. *If the load isn't high, wouldnt I be paying for extra DB server for no reason?*